# Electron.io key in obj JavaScript key is undefined?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am developing a desktop app with Electron.io. I have some data coming back from a firebase DB and am trying to match some user info with `key in obj` but it throws an error in the electron console. I have pasted the same exact code on a normal web page and it returns fine. So what is it about electron desktop development that it throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined` Here is my code:

JS:

```
firebase.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.log('dataSnapshot: ',dataSnapshot.val());
    var userData = dataSnapshot.val();

    //see if user and password match
    for(key in userData){
      if(JSON.stringify(userData[key].user) === JSON.stringify(payload.data.userName) && JSON.stringify(userData[key].password) === JSON.stringify(payload.data.password)){
        console.log('true');
      }
    };

});
```

Comment: `var key in userData`.

Comment: That worked. Can you explain why setting it with var works and why a browser with a normal html doc doesnt throw the reference error?

Comment: you didn't declare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron is probably running your code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Strict mode will throw a `ReferenceError` if you try to assign a value to a variable that hasn't yet been defined. This helps prevent you from accidentally declaring global variables.

> Assignments which would accidentally create global variables instead throw in strict mode:

Add the `'use strict';` directive to the top of your file or function to evaluate the code with the strict rules in the browser.

You can fix it by adding `var` to your loop binding.

```
for(var key in userData){
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That explains it, and that is exactly why. I didn't even think that was the issue. Thanks!